# Difference between record-send-total and manually counted number of sent messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, jmx-exporter

I have a producer that sends messages for 15 second.
I wanted to investigate the total number of messages sent to the broker.
The first method I employed involved counting messages "manually", i.e.:

```
// ...
private int sentMessages = 0;

@Override
public void run() {
   sendMessage(msg));
   sentMessages++;
}
```

The second method I used involved analysing the producer's metrics.

I compared the number of produced messages, and significantly different results I observed baffled me. `sendMessages` was equal to `65243` whereas the producer's `record-sent-total` was equal `47883`.

What might be the reason behind such a great difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe sendMessage(msg) processing in asynchronous way. So some message might failed to send. Try to update sentMessages count based on successful response.

Comment: But shouldn't then `record-error-total` be different than 0? Some messages might indeed have failed because the number I obtained with kafka-run-class to count messages is closer to `record-sent-total`. But still, it is bewildering that in such a case `record-error-total` is zero and not equal to the difference between sentMessages and `record-sent-total`...